# Twitter4J with mod_proxy

Tags: twitter4j, mod-proxy

I'm using twitter4j to post tweets from an application which only can contact a proxy to the internet. So I set up on the proxy an apache virtualhost with this config:

```
ProxyPass           /rest/1.1/  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
ProxyPassReverse    /rest/1.1/  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
```

So my application request will be a POST to https://proxy.com/rest/1.1/update.... which will be proxied to the Twitter Rest API (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/update...), so far so good. 

In order to comply with the auth-header, the oauth signature within the header is computed for every request with the original twitter api url (otherwise the authentication will fail, because the host url will be the proxy one). The POST request itselfs succeed, but an additional error is throw:

```
{"errors":[{"code":220,"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."}]}
```

I have no clue, what more to do. BTW: The same application code succeeds with a direct connection to api.twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

Okay, call me an idiot. The correct overridden method should include the access token (and not null):

```
@Override
public String getAuthorizationHeader(HttpRequest req) {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug(req.getURL());
        logger.debug(req.getRequestHeaders().toString());
    }

    //replace proxy url with twitterapi only for signature!!
    String restBaseUrl = this.conf.getRestBaseURL();
    String twitterRestBaseUrl = this.twitterRestBaseUrl;
    String modUrl = req.getURL().replace(restBaseUrl, twitterRestBaseUrl);

    //generate Token from stored values in provided config
    AccessToken token = new AccessToken(conf.getOAuthAccessToken(), conf.getOAuthAccessTokenSecret());

    return super.generateAuthorizationHeader(req.getMethod().name(), modUrl, req.getParameters(), token);
}
```

Still not sure if the replacement of the proxy url is needed, but now it works.....